# Print function code with parameters JS

Tags: javascript, function

I want to get all function code (with parameters) and print it in div.code

html file

```
<script src='script.js'></script>
...
<input type=text value='text' id='my_input'>
<div class='code'></div>
<script>
   document.querySelectorAll('div.code')[0].innerHTML=func(document.getElementById('my_input'));
</script>
```

script.js

```
function func(param){
console.log(param);
}
```

So in div.code it should be

```
"function func(text){
    console.log(text)
    }"
```

What should I use to do it ? I tried to use toString, toSource, JSON.stringify but it does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `String()` to create string from function code

```
function f(param) {
    console.log(param);
}

alert( String(f) );
// ...innerHTML = String(f);
```

If you want to replace `param` with your input you can operate on `String(f)` result as on string

```
alert( String(f).replace(/param/g, 'text') );
// ...innerHTML = String(f).replace(/param/g, document.getElementById('my_input'));
```

Take a look at this [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/awb8bysx/)

---

Also read here more about [String() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp)

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
 f.toString();
```

```js
function f(a, b, c) {

}

document.write(f.toString().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend calling the vanilla toString function of the `Function` Object to stringify your function like this:

```
Function.prototype.toString.call(yourFunctionHere);
//or just use it directly on your function, if you're not going to modify the prototype
yourFunction.toString();
```

This prints your function like you mentioned.

If you want to replace values afterwards, you can use `replace` in combination with regex.

Like this:

```
function myFunction(param1){
    alert(param1);
}

Function.prototype.toString.call(myFunction).replace(new RegExp('param1', 'g'), 'theParam');
```

This will give you the following:

```
"function myFunction(theParam){
    alert(theParam);
 }"
```